# How to add an exisiting Linux virtual machine to virtual network in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have configured a CMS solution in my Linux Virtual Machine on Azure and want to add this VM with my Virtual Netork. I am unable to add my existing Linux Virual machine to Virtual Network.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask if this Linux VM is already running on Windows Azure Virtual Machines section and what is the Linux OS?

Comment: Yes, the Linux OS is CentOS 6.2 and creating using gallery image. VM is running and listed into virtual machine section too.

Comment: Not supported: [Unable to create Linux VM inside a Virtual Network](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/thread/9fac0acd-7d44-4061-8f39-46bbdb54b665/): "Tuesday, June 12, 2012 1:41 PM: The use of Virtual Networks with Linux through the portal is not fully supported at this point.  We are actively working to fully test and enable this feature in the portal..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your Linux VM was created first and Virtual Network (VNet) was created after, your Linux VM may not be able to see the Virtual Network.(This is a known issues with Linux VM)

You can follow given steps to achieve your objective:

1. Delete the current VM (this will still keep the VHD stored in Azure Storage)
2. Now go to Virtual Machines > Disks, and find the OS disk you want to use and select Delete Disk. This does not delete the VHD, only unregisters it as a disk
3. Now create an OS image from your Saved VHD, which was use for previous VM
4. Now create a VM from OS image (#3)

This way you will have your VM ready and now to add it to VNet.

Now because you are using Linux VM to connect with VNet, there is one problem. You can not do it with your Linux VM as Windows Azure Manager Portal does not support this feature so you would need to use PowerShell command (on Windows) or Cross-Platform tools (on Mac and Linux) to achieve your objective.

Following are the command you will use to create a new VM using an OS Image and Virtual Network:

$vm = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmname -InstanceSize ExtraSmall -ImageName $image | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux –LinuxUser $linuxUser -Password $adminPassword  | Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames $subnet

New-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -AffinityGroup $affinitygroup -VNetName $vnetname -VMs $vm

Comment: This worked for me; thanks! As of a few months ago, Microsoft added better support for Linux VMs, so I was able to use the Azure portal and this tip to create new VMs using the existing VHDs and add the new VMs to a new VNet, whereas before they were just standalone VMs. I am a total Azure noob so this is in a tutorial environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the Vnet manually, there are a plenty of solutions.

One of them is to delete the curent virtual machine after you've made an image of it.

1. Create an image of the Virtual Machine (this will save the state and all the parameters of it as an image).
2. Delete the current Virtual Machine.
3. Create a new Virtual Machine from the image you previously created.
4. In the creation, make sure to select the right Vnet and the right ressources group associated.

Your Virtual Machine may now use the right Vnet.

Answer (score -2):

> http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-enable-linux-on-its-windows-azure-cloud-in-2012/11508
>
> To date, Microsoft has been balking at customer requests to add
>   persistent VMs to Azure, hoping to get customers to develop Azure apps
>   from scratch instead
>   ...
>
> Running Linux on Azure has been a
>   surprisingly big  business-customer request, as well, my contacts
>   said
>   ...
>
> The Register reported earlier this year that Microsoft was
>   testing the ability to run Linux on Azure in its own labs, and that
>   the launch of such a capability was still months away.

There are tons of VPS services out there where you can run any OS you want, quite reliably and quite inexpensively.  Apparently, Azure isn't one of them :)

Comment: This OP question was posted a few weeks after the Azure pre-release IaaS service was made available for public use - with support for a few flavors of both Windows Server and Linux. I don't think some glitches with this early beta constitutes Microsoft being unable to run reliable and cost-efficient Linux infrastructure on Azure.